# Export SPD List Workflow to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, solution-package, reusable

is it possible to export a SPD List associated workflow into a .wsp-Package for further editing in Visual Studio 2010? Since it is possible with reusable workflows i wanted to know whether it is possible with list associated workflows as well..

Kind Regards,

Peter

Comment: This guy has explained it really well: http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2012/10/converting-a-list-workflow-to-a-re-usable-workflow/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box, no, you can't save it as a template (wsp) that you can then edit in Visual Studion. However, you can still get to the XOML files that create it. By going through All Files>Workflows. With a lot of work, you can take these and pull them into Visual Studio to create a re-usable workflow from VS. This is not easy, though. Paul Schaeflein has a blog post here: http://mindsharpblogs.com/paul/archive/2008/03/12/4434.html with some of the steps, and you can always contact him via his new blog site: http://www.schaeflein.net/blog/default.aspx or on twitter to see if you can get more information.